# Javascript object - using array value as key

Tags: javascript

I have the following array

```
  const lastThreeYearsArr = [currYear, currYear-1, currYear-2 ]
```

I need to define an object as:

```
var obj = {lastThreeYearsArr[0]: 0, lastThreeYearsArr[1]: 0, lastThreeYearsArr[2]: 0};
```

But using the array as key doesn't seem to work in javascript. Is there a way to access the array value and put it as key in the object.

Comment: [Computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a new object by iterating the keys and use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) with [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names).

```js
var lastThreeYearsArr = ['currYear', 'currYear-1', 'currYear-2'],
    object = lastThreeYearsArr.reduce((o, k) => Object.assign(o, { [k]: 0 }), {});
    
console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the properties using bracket notation instead of the object literal notation.  For example:

```
const x = [2011, 2012, 2013]
let y = {}
y[x[0]] = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

use a simple [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/forEach) and assign new properties with [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) :

```js
const currYear = (new Date()).getFullYear();
const lty = [currYear, currYear - 1, currYear - 2]

let result = {};

lty.forEach((e, i) => {
  result[e] = 0
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Enclose each key with brackets `[]` which are used for [**computed property names**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names)

You can use [**Object.assign**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Browser_compatibility) as already suggested but if IE compatibility is required a basic loop will do too.

```js
var currYear = 2018;
var lastThreeYearsArr = [currYear, currYear - 1, currYear - 2]

var obj = {};

for (var i = 0; i < lastThreeYearsArr.length; i++) {
    obj[lastThreeYearsArr[i]] = 0;
}

console.log(obj);
```